# Is it safe to use IHttpClientFactory (that reuses the HttpClientHandlers between requests) when I have to connect to different tenant's APIs?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, multi-tenant, httpclientfactory

My use case: I'm writing an app that needs to connect to a multitenant API. The base address, headers, and authentication for each request will vary from request to request.

I came across the concept of `IHttpClientFactory` in .NET Core, and I think I understand the underlying logic. It gives you a new `HttpClient` every time; `HttpClientHandlers` (what is doing the work) are created and managed by `IHttpClientFactory` and potentially can be reused.

My question: is it safe to use `IHttpClientFactory` (that reuses the `HttpClientHandlers` between requests) when I have to connect to different tenant's APIs? - thus different endpoints / base address / headers / auth. Can info from one request leak or contaminate the subsequent request?

I will create new `HttpMessageRequest` objects for each call, and I will have different `HttpClient`s provided by `IHttpClientFactory`, yes...

PS: From [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookies) Microsoft discloses `CookieContainer`'s are shared and that if you have cookie handling requirements, stay away from `IHttpClientFactory` or disable Cookie handling.

Answer (score 1):

It is said when using IClientFactory, you need

- Disable the cookie https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#cookies
- Don't  cache scope-related information (such as data from HttpContext) inside HttpMessageHandler and use scoped dependencies with caution to avoid leaking sensitive information. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#message-handler-scopes-in-ihttpclientfactory

Just using httpclient with setting the `PooledConnectionLifetime` to desired interval is also recommanded.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines#recommended-use

Comment: Yup, I added the link to Microsoft documentation for this. Thanks for clarifying the Cookie handling part.